# Why is it not behaving as expected during T-Locoh elongation?

Tags: r

I am working with `T-Locoh` and while trying to do elongation it is not working as like as I expected.

#### Console Output:

```
> f_10193.lhs.k15<-lhs.ellipses.add(f_10193.lhs.k15, id=NULL, k=NULL, r=NULL, a=NULL, s=NULL, hs.names=NULL, status=TRUE, beep=FALSE, save.ellipses = TRUE, existing.ellipses = c("overwrite","abort")[1])
ID.pts3916.k15.s1e-04.kmin0
  Calculating enclosing ellipses 
   |+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ | 97% ~05s          
Error in solve.default(X) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.13932e-17
> traceback()
7: solve.default(X)
6: solve(X)
5: diag(t(Q) %*% solve(X) %*% Q)
4: mvee(p@Polygons[[1]]@coords[-nrow(p@Polygons[[1]]@coords), ], 
       plotme = FALSE, tolerance = 0.005, no.ellipse.val = 2, checks = checks)
3: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2: pblapply(lhs[[hs.idx]][["hulls"]]@polygons, function(p) mvee(p@Polygons[[1]]@coords[-nrow(p@Polygons[[1]]@coords), 
       ], plotme = FALSE, tolerance = 0.005, no.ellipse.val = 2, 
       checks = checks))
1: lhs.ellipses.add(f_10193.lhs.k15, id = NULL, k = NULL, r = NULL, 
       a = NULL, s = NULL, hs.names = NULL, status = TRUE, beep = FALSE, 
       save.ellipses = TRUE, existing.ellipses = c("overwrite", 
           "abort")[1])
```

Comment: Could you please broaden your question a bit? It's a tad tough to see what you're asking exactly. Do read the [tour]!

Comment: Can you provide some more information, e.g. code, additional packages and so on.

Comment: Ops...sorry, I'm new and I can't use very well R.

Comment: The packages is (tlocoh). The code is (lhs.ellipses.add)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add  code and more description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!